# Перенос строки в VSCode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

уважаемые, столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда альт табаюсь в браузер или еще что-то, то строка переносится автоматически, может кто сталкивался?
До альт таба:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и после:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал найти что-то в json файле, может когда-то что-то накрутил, но там ничего нет, буду рад, если кто-то поможет)

Хорошего всем дня!